# How can transfer data from one function to another function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

using sortable jquery how can I transfer variable data from one function to another function,
I have

```
start:function(event,ui){ var data="xyz";}
```

and

```
receive:function(event,ui){
}
```

I want the value of var data in `receive:function(event,ui){}`
How can I get this?

Comment: first of all, this example doesn't make sense as you are just declaring the variable and not doing anything with it.

If the variable has to be in `start` then only way you can access the value is by returning the variable value from the `start` function.

So, now you can call start function from receive function and get the value.

Comment: the easiest you can do is to declare data as a global value. Alternatively, there are a tons more ways to accomplish the same, though a global declaration is absolutely enough here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will fulfill your conditions.Just try it.

```
 var radio;
    var name;
    getdata() {
        radio = document.getElementsByName("radiobuttonlist");
        name=document.getElementById("Firstnametext").value;
        // VALUE UPDATED HERE
    }
    sendinfo() {
        // VARIABLE ACCESSIBLE HERE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is you want to do something like this, without having to call start

```
start: function(event, ui) {
    var data = 'xyz';
    // Do something with data
    window.app.data = data;
}
receive: function(event, ui) {
    var data = window.app.data;
}
```

However, you can also do this:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
    var data = 'xyz';
    // Do something with data
    return data;
}
receive: function(event, ui) {
    var data = this.start();
}
```

However, I suspect that you don't want the second one, it involves calling `start` in `receive`. Good luck on whatever you're doing